# Sum values of a table column using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have dynamically created a `table`. There is one column empty on page load but it fills values when I choose the quantity of a dropdown menu(other column) and a default price value (other column). I want to add the total values created of this process using jQuery and display the total value.

Has anyone any ideas how can I do that?I have tried a lot but no results appeared.

I try this:

```
$(document).each("[id^=total]", function(event){
  var num = this.id.slice(5);
  var sum = 0;

     var value = $('#total'+num).text();
     sum += parseFloat(this.value);

     $('#sum').text(sum);
 });
```

HTML (where the result will be displayed):

```
<tr>
   <th colspan="6" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
   <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><span id="sum"></span></th>
</tr>
```

HTML (id='qua2' is a dropdown menu from 1 to 20):

```
<tr>
    <td><center><selectclass='choose'id='qua2'></select></center></td>
    <td><center><spanid='yprice2'>101.10</span></center></td>
    <td><center><spanid='total2'></span></center></td>
</tr>
```

NOTICE:

Column `total` is created after table creation.I choose a value of dropdown and makes this process (value of dropdown * price).Result displayed in column total.

UPDATED (I use this script but the result in `id='sum'` is `NaN`) :

```
$(document).on('change', "[id^=qua]", function(event){
var num = this.id.slice(3);
var sum = 0;
var value = $("#qua"+num).val();
var yprc = $("#yprice"+num).text();
var amount = value * yprc;
amount = amount.toFixed(2);

var $sum = $("#sum");
var $total = $("#total"+num);

    $total.html(amount);

 $("[id^=total]").each(function(){
 sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
 });
 $sum.text(sum);
});
```

Comment: Could you post some example html please.

Comment: $('#total'+num).val();  tried?

Comment: Yes i did but still the same.

Comment: I updated my question!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/347/)**.

What I suggest is to avoid the use of id's and use classes instead :

```
calc_total();

$(".choose").on('change', function(){
  var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
  var price  = parseFloat($('.price',parent).text());
  var choose = parseFloat($('.choose',parent).val());

  $('.total',parent).text(choose*price);

  calc_total();
});

function calc_total(){
  var sum = 0;
  $(".total").each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
  });
  $('#sum').text(sum);
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
calc_total();

$(".choose").on('change', function(){
  var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
  var price  = parseFloat($('.price',parent).text());
  var choose = parseFloat($('.choose',parent).val());

  $('.total',parent).text(choose*price);

  calc_total();
});

function calc_total(){
  var sum = 0;
  $(".total").each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
  });
  $('#sum').text(sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <select class='choose'>
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
        </select>
      </center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <span class='price'>100</span>
      </center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <span class='total'>100</span>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <select class='choose'>
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
        </select>
      </center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <span class='price'>100</span>
      </center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <span class='total'>100</span>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <select class='choose'>
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
        </select>
      </center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <span class='price'>100</span>
      </center>  
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <span class='total'>100</span>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><span id="sum"></span></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but still nothing.It seems pretty simple but I cannot figure this out.

Comment: The one in my answer?

Comment: Check my suggestion please.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!The problem is that the result is like a string.(ex. 0150230850).Not like 150+230+850 = 1230.Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Try this way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sum Total for Column in jQuery </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table thead th').each(function (i) {
                calculateColumn(i);
            });
        });
        function calculateColumn(index) {
            var total = 0;
            $('table tr').each(function () {
                var value = parseInt($('td', this).eq(index).text());
                if (!isNaN(value)) {
                    total += value;
                }
            });
            $('table tfoot td').eq(index).text('Total: ' + total);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ITEM 1</th>
                <th>ITEM 2</th>
                <th>ITEM 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td>Total:</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if i want to exclude one column to find sum

Comment: Great one. How can i apply this on multitables with ajax? i.e ''var tables = $('table.display').each(function () {    my things  });''?